# AWS ELB and forcing Https

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have an ELB which in the first place was set to forward in this way:

```
Protocal    Port    Forward-Protocol    Port
Http         80          Http            80
Protocal    Port    Forward-Protocol    Port
Https        443         Https           443
```

Since I added my SSL certificate to the ELB and my EC2 instance is inside a private subnet, the AWS support engineer suggested to change https to forward to http as follow:

```
Protocal    Port    Forward-Protocol    Port
Http         80          Http            80
Protocal    Port    Forward-Protocol    Port
Https        443         Http            80
```

He said its a better practice since the ELB already doing everything need in the Https do there is no reason to add overhead to my instance as well.

The problem is that in my EC2 instance my folder structure is:

- /var/www/html - for regular http requests
- /var/www/secure - for secured https requests.

I want to force my site to do only Https requests so I want to use this code in my *.80 Virtual:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
#Force the https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
#Here i need a rule to change the document root.
...
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem with this code is that it will transfer the request the https, while probably what i need is to change the document root when its https.

I can assume that if it got to the http with a forward to https - the connection is already secured.

Comment: Why do you have different document roots for HTTP/HTTPS? Do you have different content in the two folders?

Comment: Used to.. But i might mirgrate both

Comment: You should definitely look into having everything in the same document root. I've never seen a use case where you split the document root depending on if it's requested with HTTP or HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

With your rewrite rule all traffic will be secure - so there's no need for the files in the non-secure folder.

I would delete the existing html folder and rename the 'secure' folder 'html'.